# Attempting to plot the period-3 boundary of the Mandelbrot Set in Desmos

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, graphing-functions

I'm trying to graph the period-3 boundary of the Mandelbrot set in Desmos (taken from [this paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1995-123-12/S0002-9939-1995-1301497-3/S0002-9939-1995-1301497-3.pdf)), but I'm getting a "Definitions are nested too deeply" error. I understand that this is because of how Desmos uses trees to calculate everything, and Desmos calculates every instance of a function when it comes across it in the tree, but this seems to working against me in my case. For instance, I have a function "radius" that simply gets the radius given *x* and *y*, and another function "Sqrt" that calls "radius" twice with the same values of *x* and *y*. From my understanding, Desmos will do two separate calculations for "radius", rather than storing the value that "radius" returns and using it again later (like a temporary variable in C or any programming language). Now I have several nested functions like this, and so very quickly the tree becomes exponentially bigger - thus causing this error. The only way I've found to get past this error is to expand the equations out completely so I get separate equations for the real and imaginary coordinates - a feat that required several hours of copying and pasting, and ideally not the end result here.

As such, my questions are:

1. Is there a way to avoid this error by using functions like variables in C? In other words, store a value to some variable, and call upon it later when I need it rather than recalculate it every time?
2. If not, are there known simplifications I can do to the boundary equations to avoid the problem? I'm currently only approximating the period-3 boundary, but for my purposes I'd like to graph the actual curve.

My Desmos graph can be accessed [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bp4pnnt9au) for more information.

Comment: Does this endeavor have to be in Desmos? If not, I highly suggest using python or MATLAB instead.

Comment: Also, Desmos does not support the use of writing data to variables, believe me I've tried. That being said. "programming" in Desmos using fancy math tricks is possible as it's Turing Complete, but inevitably leads to errors like the one's you've encountered.

Comment: I suppose not, but I have always used Desmos to solve my problems and I have never used Matlab before (although I probably should take advantage of the free license my school gives me...)